# appending while loop string into json response message

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

Im trying to take my sql query and loop data into a string so that it can be put into the response message for printing on returning to html page. Im sure there is a much better way to do this but I have very little knowledge on jquery, etc...

I have appended the string into the response message which shows up fine in the browser but the data from the string does not show up at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. See code below...

PHP

```
    $find = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

        $datprint = "";
        while ( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($find)) { 

            $datprint .= $row2['FirstName'];
            $datprint .= $row2['LastName'];
            $datprint .= $row2['Site_ID']; 
            $datprint .= $row2['Title'];
            $datprint .= $row2['Message'];

        }

        $response = array('type'=>'', 'message'=>'');

        $response['type'] = 'success';
        $response['message'] = "Thank-You for submitting the form!<div id='printHTML'> ".$datprint." </div><hr>";   
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $response['type'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: What is the result of `json_last_error()`?  Do you get a jQuery error on the client side?

Comment: I dont get any errors, the <div> and <hr> all come through but it blank on where the string should have started.

Comment: maybe query isn't returning anything..check `num_rows()`.. if zero send back `$sql2`  string to see what it looks like

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).